# Using string formatting in sqlite execute statement is raising errors

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I am getting syntax error while using variable to insert data in sql table . I don't know why.

this is a piece of the code

```py
        global uni_username
        global user_and_pass
        username1 = uni_username.get()
        print(username1)
        site_name = site_e.get()
        user_id = n_u_name_e.get()
        user_password = n_u_p_e.get()

        cursr.execute(f"INSERT INTO {username1} 
    (site_name,user_id,user_password) VALUES {site_name},{user_id}, 
    {user_password}",
                      )

        connection.commit()
        cursr.execute(f"SELECT rowid, * FROM {username1} ")
        sites_name = (cursr.fetchall())
        print(sites_name)
```

this is error

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python3.9\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1885, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\NK Infosystem\PycharmProjects\password tkinter\main.py", line 91, in save_new_form
    cursr.execute(f"INSERT INTO {username1} (site_name,user_id,user_password) VALUES {site_name},{user_id},{user_password}",
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

I tried these both but still showing same error

```
  cursr.execute(f'''INSERT INTO {username1} (site_name,user_id,user_password) VALUES ({site_name},{user_id},{user_password}) ''')
```

```
        cursr.execute(f'''INSERT INTO {username1} (site_name,user_id,user_password) VALUES (?,?,?)''', (site_name,user_id,user_password) )
```

Comment: why do you have 'f' before query?

Comment: to use variable into this

Comment: Can you give a sample Username? Is it a Table Name?

Comment: username1 is table name

Comment: You need to have **brackets** around the values - use: `VALUES ( {site_name}, {user_id}, {user_password} )` - as a quick peak at the [official SQLite documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) would have **easily showed you** ....

Comment: still geting the same error

Comment: try removing the comma after the query

Comment: ```cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO {username1}(site_name,user_id,user_password)',(site_name,user_id,user_password)) ```

I am not sure if this will work...

Comment: nope this is also not working

Comment: Try printing the query before executing it, it's obviously in a funky state after formatting, `username1` is likely not what you expect.

Comment: Is it still syntax error though? @Masklinn that still shouldn't give a syntax error tbh. probably 'some no such Table' error

Comment: @AdityaGupta no, depending how broken the contents of the variable is it could well generate SQL that's entirely syntactically invalid. sqlite first needs to parse the query, then it can check if the various bits make sense. You'd only get a "no such table" if the first step succeeds, but here it obviously fails.

Comment: ya actually it was not getting table name

Comment: @acw1668 yah it is working

Comment: @AdityaGupta can you tell me how my code is https://github.com/aadityabaj/python-projects.git in patch 1

Comment: Instead of using string formatting to set `VALUES(...)` in SQL statements, use parameter substitution as described in the [Python sqlite3 socs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3).  This will prevent many issues with formatting values correctly.